# SQL: get maximum value and it's corresponding field(s)

Tags: sql

I need to get the max lesson_score from the following table, along with the respective date for a particular user:

```
--------------------------------
|uid |lesson_score |date       |
--------------------------------
|1   |2            |1391023460 |
|1   |8            |1391023518 |
|1   |4            |1391023596 |
--------------------------------
```

I need a result of:

```
---------------------------
|lesson_score |date       |
---------------------------
|8            |1391023596 |
---------------------------
```

My SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT date, MAX(lesson_score) AS lesson_score 
FROM cdu_user_session_progress 
WHERE uid = 1 
GROUP BY date";
```

But it just gives me three rows:

```
---------------------------
|lesson_score |date       |
---------------------------
|2            |1391023460 |
|4            |1391023596 |
|8            |1391023518 |
---------------------------
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
SELECT lesson_score, date FROM cdu_user_session_progress ORDER BY lesson_score DESC LIMIT 1;
```

The `ORDER BY` - part is responsible, that the max. lession_score will be fetched at the beginning.

After the order-by, you get the folling result:

```
---------------------------
|lesson_score |date       |
---------------------------
|8            |1391023518 |
|4            |1391023596 |
|2            |1391023460 |
---------------------------
```

Now the `LIMIT`-part says, that the database should only return the first row - all other result-rows will be ignored, and the result is this:

```
---------------------------
|lesson_score |date       |
---------------------------
|8            |1391023518 |
---------------------------
```

In order to get the minium-score, you just write `ASC` intead of `DESC` (or remove it, because `ASC` is the default-value)

Comment: And what if I want the minimum lesson_score?

Comment: use ASC instead of DESC

Comment: Updated the answer. `DESC` means "descending", and `ASC` stands for "ascending"

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT date, MAX(lesson_score) AS lesson_score 
FROM cdu_user_session_progress 
WHERE uid = 1 
GROUP BY date";
```

MAX is an aggregation function, it will return maximum of lesson_score if there are multiple value for lesson_score

In your query the value is always same so it returns that. Remember SELECT MAX(...) does not work on whole table records, it works each record one by one.

You can get your result using order by like this

```
SELECT   top 1 date, lesson_score AS lesson_score 
FROM     cdu_user_session_progress 
WHERE    uid = 1 
ORDER BY lesson_score DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you want the group by? just use `Order BY ColumnName DESC LIMIT 1` in your query it is returning all the records because `UID=1` is true for all the records and its just grouping it by date shows `MAX` for each `DATE`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [date], lesson_score
FROM cdu_user_session_progress
WHERE lesson_score = (SELECT MAX(lesson_score) FROM cdu_user_session_progress GROUP BY [ui] HAVING [uid] = 1)
    AND [uid] =1;
```